# Can znapzend be used for replication only?

Tags: znapzend

Is there a recommended znapzend plan to specify when using znapzend for replication only?

I've been able to make it work by specifying a src and dst plan of ''1s=>15min' which essentially says do a snap-and-send every 15 minutes and retain it for 1 second (so all old snaps get destroyed after each replication - at least that's what I'm aiming for).

For the most part this seems to work fine.  However, in the event that something goes wrong with the send-recv, such as running out of disk space, all the destination snapshots will be destroyed during the cleanup stage - I've watched this happen with the --debug option.  This gets me into a state of having no snapshots on dest and no more working replica.

I'm actually suprised to find that there are situations where znapzend would remove my previous snapshot from the destination without having successully created the next snapshot, but I'm probably exercising an unusual corner case here.  Maybe I've encountered a bug that has been fixed in newer versions?

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading znapzend from 0.17.0 to 0.19.0 the problem of the last snapshot being deleted on the destination has been eliminated.